# Simulating slow down of disk operations

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-disk, read, write

we know that there exist some excellent tool like `netem` which make it possible to slow down network parameters (like bandtwidth and so on).

Is there exists analogous tool for simulating slow down on disk operations, like read/writes ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate it over `cgroups`. Especially for this reasons `blkio` controller was developed. You should paste program in this group and set appropriate I/O parameters (especially bandwidth). [`blkio` documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/cgroup-v1/blkio-controller.txt). Basic info about `cgroups` mechanism located in [kernel documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt).